# I cannot get the tabbar delegate to call

Tags: ios, swift, tabs

I have asked this problem b4 and have tried for so long...

Problem: I have 4 tabs, when the third one is selected i want to wait until the tab has been changed, then send info to a Stringbuilder etc. But I can never seem to get it to call properly, I have tried delegating the genreViewController and tried to use the protocols but it never calls...

Please tell me what I need to put inside of the tab bar function since I do not know what should be there. I have tried putting the tabbarcontroller there and select viewcontroller. I am very new to all this so please dont be harsh :(

TabBarController:

```
import UIKit
class TabBarViewController: UITabBarController{

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func tabBar(_ tabBar: TabBarViewController, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
        print("he")
        //ask where it is first tab bar item
        if self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex == 1 {
            print("genres")

        }

    }

}
```

GenreViewController:

```
import UIKit

class GenreViewController: UIViewController,     UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var genreSwitch: UISwitch!

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //self.tabBarController?.delegate = self
        tableView.isScrollEnabled = false
        let tabBarViewController = TabBarViewController()



    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    let genreArray = ["Action","Adventure","Comedy","Fantasy","Drama","Horror","Romance","Thriller","Family"]
    let genreIds = [28,12,35,14,18,27,10749,53,10751]
    //LATER!!: Save this Array until next time they log into the app
    var activeGenreArray = [Int!](repeating: 0, count: 9)





    //Number of rows
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return genreArray.count
    }


    //What to do with tableview
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! GenreCustomcell


        cell.genreSwitch.isEnabled = true
        cell.genreName.text = self.genreArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.genreSwitch.setOn(false, animated: true)

        cell.genreSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(GenreViewController.switchChange(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
        cell.genreSwitch.restorationIdentifier = "\(genreIds[indexPath.row])"
        cell.genreSwitch.tag = indexPath.row


        return cell
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    func switchChange(sender: UISwitch){

        let id = Int(sender.restorationIdentifier!)
        let row = Int(sender.tag)
        print(row)

        if sender.isOn == true{
            activeGenreArray[row] = id!
            print(activeGenreArray)
        }
        else{

            activeGenreArray[row] = 0

            print(activeGenreArray)
        }

    }




}


class GenreCustomcell: UITableViewCell{

    @IBOutlet weak var genreName: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var genreSwitch: UISwitch!

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me what you are trying to do here. You've declared your `GenreViewController` to be a `UITabBarControllerDelegate` but then implemented a `UITabBarControllerDelegate` method (`tabBar:didSelect:`) on your `TabBarViewController` subclass of `UITabBarController`.

I would expect to see you have:

1. a reference to some `UITabBarController` (this could be more specifically a `TabBarViewController`)
2. a reference to some `UITabBarControllerDelegate` (this could be a `GenreViewController`, a `TabBarViewController` if it should be its own delegate, or some other object entirely)
3. to set the `UITabBarController` instance's `delegate` property to be the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` instance.

Things that may have confused you:

- A view controller can exist (and be associated with a tab) but does
  not load it's view until it is needed (i.e. you are switching to its
  tab). If you added your `GenreViewController` to a tab bar controller
  it's `viewDidLoad` method will not be called until the tab bar
  controller switches to that tab the first time. If your
  `GenreViewController` was setting its own tab bar controller's
  delegate in `viewDidLoad` (e.g. `self.tabbarController?.delegate =
  self`) it may not become the tab bar controller's delegate when you
  expected and so would not be notified of changes in the selected tab
  until after it had been selected once.
- It's not clear what the `let tabBarViewController =
  TabBarViewController()` line is meant to do but that is creating a
  new `TabBarViewController` which is not the one you might already be
  seeing in your window. Creating a new instance of a class is not equivalent to referencing some existing instance of that same class.

Comment: Aha! So I have to switch out the UItabbarcontroller with my TabbarViewController. I do see what you mean. But my main problem is when do i make my own tabbarController vs just using delegate? Since having both seems pointless. But I will only use the tabBar method once. When the user jumps from tabbar item 3 to any other tabbaritem. @Jonah